# how to read a matrix from text file in R

Tags: r

I have a text file name "A.txt" . In there , I have the following data:

```
1 3 4 
2 3 4 
5 6 7
```

I want to read it and save as A vector in R software . How can I do that ?

Update :

I have tried by the following code :

```
R> dat <- as.numeric(readLines('D:/Simplex/SimplexInitialTheoryWithRsoftware/src/A.txt'))
R>  dat.matrix <- matrix(dat, nrow=??)
```

But I have the following error .

Eror: unexpected ')' in "dat.matrix <- matrix(dat, nrow=??)"

I am very new in this software . Please help me

Comment: Just read as a data.frame with `read.table` and use `as.matrix` (or `unlist` if you really want an atomic vector).

Comment: Roland , can you see the update ?

Comment: Error: unexpected ')' in "dat.matrix <- matrix(dat, nrow=??)"

Comment: @osimer pothe you mentioned that you wanted to `read it and save as A vector`.  So, I don't understand the `matrix(dat, nrow=??)` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this
Define matrix with column header:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 
1 3 4 
2 3 4 
5 6 7 
d<-read.table("/home/shad/Desktop/A.txt",header=TRUE,sep=" ")
```

then access it like:

```
d[1,1]
d[1,2]
```

For numeric conversion see [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13145465/1363495)
Hope it helps

Answer (score 12):

From the way you've started out it looks like you're searching for the `scan` function.

```
mat <- scan('A.txt')
mat <- matrix(mat, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. But actually I am generating a[   ][   ] matrix by java file . Here row and col are also generated randomly . So no of row is not fixed  .

Comment: But you asked to read it in as vector. If you want it read in as a matrix read it in with a `read.table` command but give it all the information it needs, as Roland suggested. `read.table` is one of those rare commands that actually has a very useful help in R. Then just use `as.matrix`.

Answer (score 3):

The post is a bit old, but the answers are valid until today.

```
aa <- as.matrix(read.table("A.txt", sep=" "))
```

Comment: nice answer, @AMS, but parenthesis missing on right, thus: `aa <- as.matrix(read.table("A.txt", sep=" "))`